# Some rows, where a column value is zero, are not deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete the entire row which contains a zero in specific column.

All the cells with value zero in that column are not getting deleted. Some cells still remain with the value zero.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ChkRange As Range
Set ChkRange = Range("A2:A150")

For Each cell In ChkRange
    If cell = "0" Then
        cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I also tried range from "A150:A2"

Comment: When deleting rows, you need to iterate backward, or some rows can be skipped.

Comment: So if i give a range "A150:A2" wont it work?

Comment: That isn't iterating.  See answer below for what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you are needing to test for a string value that = "0"  and not a number = 0.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim iRow as Integer

For iRow = 150 to 2 Step -1
  If Cells(iRow, "A") = "0" Then
    Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
  End If
Next

End Sub
```